# How can I replace the template of the scaffold_controller generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rails-generators

When we use the command `rails g scaffold Post title content` it will generate many files according to some templates located inside railties.

There is even a command that we can copy all templates to our application:

`rake app:templates:copy`

But there is one template that isn't replaced by it's counterpart inside `\lib'. That's` scaffold_controller/controller.rb.tt`. I'm trying to search how can I replace this with no luck so far.

So that's my question. How can I change the template that writes the controller when we are scaffolding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To override controller scaffolding generator use `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb.tt`

```
echo 'Overriden for rails g scaffold' > lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb.tt
```

```
rails g scaffold user > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Overriden for rails g scaffold
```

```
rails g scaffold_controller posts > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Overriden for rails g scaffold
```

2. To override controller generator use `lib/templates/rails/controller/controller.rb.tt`

```
echo 'Overriden for rails g controller' > lib/templates/rails/controller/controller.rb.tt
```

```
rails g controller books index > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat app/controllers/books_controller.rb
Overriden for rails g controller
```